# Python program start

Tags: python

Should I start a Python program with:

```
if__name__ == '__main__':
some code...
```

And if so, why? I saw it many times but don't have a clue about it.

Comment: @Kirill Titov: Please don't edit the question to say "Closed".  It isn't closed.  You selected an answer -- that's perfect, and all you ever need to do.  Doing more is confusing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If your program is usable as a library but you also have a main program (e.g. to test the library), that construct lets others import the file as a library and not run your main program. If your program is named foo.py and you do "import foo" from another python file, `__name__` evaluates to `'foo'`, but if you run "python foo.py" from the command line, `__name__` evaluates to `'__main__'`.

Note that you do need to insert a space between if and _, and indent the main program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main program here
```

Comment: +1: Reuse is important.  A module can have 2 lives.  As main program.  As component in some other main program.  As main program is DOES things.  As component, it merely defines things.

Comment: This may go without saying, but be sure that this conditional goes at the end of your file.

Answer (score 25):

A better pattern is this:

```
def main():
   ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

This allows your code to be invoked by someone who imported it, while also making programs such as [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) and [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/projects/pylint) work.

Comment: thank you! i was worried that the whole program had to be indented from the get go. I didin't like that.

Answer (score 22):

Guido Van Rossum [suggests](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829):

```
def main(argv=None):
  if argv is None:
    argv = sys.argv
  ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

This way you can run `main()` from somewhere else (supplying the arguments), and if you want to exit with an error code just `return 1` from `main()`, and it won't make an interactive interpreter exit by mistake.

Comment: Perhaps ensure the example has a return value as outlined in the text?

Comment: All functions have an implicit return value of None, which translates to an exit code of 0.

Answer (score 3):

This is good practice. First, it clearly marks your module entry point (assuming you don't have any other executable code at toplevel - yuck). Second, it makes your module importable by other modules without executing, which some tools like code checkers, packagers etc. need to do.